# The item you requested is not available for purchase - Unity3D on mobile

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to integrate Android Market in-app purchases into my app, but unfortunately coming across an annoying error every time I try to purchase a real inapp product.

I'm using `Unity3D` and Sommla framework for that. The surprising issue is I can purchase the inapp products just fine when I test run the app in the Unity Editor but every time I try to test it on my Mobile device I get the annoying error:

**The item you requested is not available for purchase**

I googled the about this error but nothing seems to work for me, I have already made sure that:

- The APK is signed and uploaded to the Developer console as alpha.
- Installed the App on the device through Unity Build App
- Have a Test Account in my developer console
- In app product is configured in the developer console and is activated
- The app version number and version code are same as they are on the developer console.

  Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

If you can purchase via test in app purchase id `android.test.purchased` and trying real id to get product in development build of android then don't worry. Once it gets live, this error will no longer be visible and you'd see the actual product with actual price.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get you. Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Bro, it is normal behaviour in development mood

Comment: So, you are saying there is no way to verify it before deploying it to the production?

Comment: Did you test it with test id? If yes then my experience would say that you should go on.. It is my experience. May be someone else would make a better answer here, someone who has more experience

Comment: What test id? Is there some test product that Google provide for Testing purposes? Bythe way, I can purchase the inapp products when I use the Unity Editor  to test the game.

Comment: You cannot purchase or test products in Editor

Answer (score 0):

I am adding some more scenarios to occur the same error:

1. The Phone Should have a valid Gmail account and need to configure in Settings account.
2. If the account is added to the Sandbox, you need to configure a valid credit card to the Gmail account. If the Gmail account has no valid credit card, the same error will come (The card won't be chargeable in Sandbox).

Comment: I may need to configure the Credit Card and check if that works. All the rest are configured.